Multiline TextField not wrapping text correctly after width change
On macOS a multiline TextField does not wrap correctly after the TextField's width changes. I wonder if anyone knows if this is a bug or if there's something that needs to be done additionally on macOS.
On iOS the text correctly re-wraps after width changes of TextField.
Initial width:

Increases width:

Reduced width:

Xcode 15.4
macOS Sonoma 14.5
Example project: here
Code:
struct Bug: View {
    
    private static let defaultWidth: CGFloat = 200
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var width: CGFloat = defaultWidth
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField(text: $text, axis: .vertical) {
                Text("Label")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: width)
            
            HStack {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.smooth) {
                        width = 100
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Smaller")
                }
                
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        width = Self.defaultWidth
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Default")
                }
                
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.smooth) {
                        width = 300
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Larger")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


you could try adding
.id(width)

to the Text("Label"). Or some custom id to force the TextField to refresh.
Edit-1:
This is the code I use to change and animate the TextField on the
action of the Buttons width changes. Works very well for me.
Tested on iMac with MacOS 15.0, Xcode 16-beta-3, not Previews.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Bug()
    }
}

struct Bug: View {
    
    private static let defaultWidth: CGFloat = 200
    
    @State private var text: String = "hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello"
    @State private var width: CGFloat = defaultWidth
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField(text: $text, axis: .vertical) {
                Text("Label").id(width)  // <--- here
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: width)

            HStack {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.smooth) {
                        width = 100
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Smaller")
                }
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        width = Self.defaultWidth
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Default")
                }
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.smooth) {
                        width = 300
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Larger")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

default size

smaller:

larger:


This breaks the animation though.

ok,I see, attach the .id(width) to the Text("Label"). Updated my answer.

Attaching .id() to the Text label did not change anything as far as I can see. I believe the label is not visible or displayed unless in a Form. Does SwiftUI re-render the parent (i.e. TextField) to update the child (i.e. Text)?

updated my answer with the code I used and the macOS info. This code works well for me. It could be different on your Xcode 15.4 macOS Sonoma 14.5, but I don't have these anymore, so I cannot test the code on that system. Maybe someone could test the code on the different systems and report the results.

Note, updated to MacOS 15.0 beta (24A5298h), Xcode 16-beta-4, and now the
TextField does not re-size correctly when I attach the .id(width)
to the Text("Label"). It does if attached to the TextField,
but then you loose the animation.
